# How to rearrange columns in Oracle SQL Developer script output

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-sql-developer

maybe this is an already answered question, but I am relatively new to Oracle DB and couldn't find my answer around the Internet.
So I have created a table in Oracle and when running the SELECT statement the output shows me columns like this:

[image: Oracle SQL Developer]

Please if anyone can explain how to rearrange the columns so, the values from CITY column go under the City column, and the Customer_Name goes under that output column. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the `format` command IIRC? Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). You could check out the articles in my profile on how to ask a question on these forums. They are a great resource and you will get all the more out of them if you follow the guidelines! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-) p.p.s. see [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1091373?start=0&tstart=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an Oracle or SQL Developer problem.

The problem is the font you use. It is variable-width and there is just no way to properly align output with that. Use a fixed-width (monospaced) font and alignment just works out of the box.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was using the default font and that was the problem. Thank you very much, sir. I marked your answer as accepted.